# QGIS problem with External Resource widget in attribute table

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes

I have the following problem and I am not sure how to fix it or if its a bug.

When setting an editor widget of a field to "External Resource" I can not access the widget from within the attribute table. When double clicking it, it shows the current path and the "..." button but I can't click on the button nor change the path manually (see the first screenshot). While accessing the same editor widget via the identify tool works fine (see the second screenshot).

[image: Attribute Table with widget does not work]

[image: identify tool]

**Question:**

Can I set the widget in some way so it works also while accessing it via attribute table or am I supposed to use the form in identify tool?

I am aware of the option, that I can set the view of the attribute table to "Form view" but this is not an option for my case.

**Set up:** 
Windows 10 64 bit with QGIS 2.14.15. I also checked that the "Editable" Checkmark is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a workaround for my problem although is not a perfect fit.

What I do is:

- In the options of the "External Resource" widget I disable the hyperlink option

[image: Window for hyperlink]

- When working inside the attribute table I double click the field, click inside the text edit widget to get the focus and then click on the button with the "..." to choose my folder.
- After finishing my edits I reenable the hyperlink option

This is obviously not a perfect solution so I would be glad someone can point me to a better one